# Timer in Pygame displaying same values

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a reaction time tester in Pygame, but the timer for each attempt is displaying 0. When the screen is red, pressing the down key is supposed to record the time taken. I'm not sure exactly where I'm supposed to place the timer, as I'm struggling to understand how the event loop actually works.

```
import pygame, sys
import random
from random import randint
import time
from time import sleep
from pygame.locals import *
FPS = 30
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Test')

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
y = False
x = 0

while True:


    if y is False:
        y = True
        DISPLAYSURF.fill(WHITE)

        start = time.time()
        sleep(randint(1,3))

    else:
        y = False
        DISPLAYSURF.fill(RED)
        time.sleep(2)



    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if x < 5:
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if y is True:
                    end = time.time()
                    print(end - start)
                    x += 1



        else:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()



    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what this is supposed to do (is the intent to time reaction speed to the change in colour?), but if I run the code and press a key while the screen is red, I do get a printout of the time that the screen was red. It's very close to whole seconds, between 1 and 3, presumably due to `sleep(randint(1,3))`. So it appears to time the red/white cycle rather than user.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the intention. I just realised that it's timing the transition between the colours rather than the time between the screen turning red and key press, so I've played around putting the timer in different places but still not getting the results I want.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `pygame` but I would imagine this requires threading. `time.sleep()` is blocking, so for single-threaded execution, I think you're always going to get stuck timing how long you persist the red screen. [This](http://inventwithpython.com/blog/2013/04/22/multithreaded-python-tutorial-with-threadworms/) seems pretty in-depth and might be overkill for this problem, but it might have some pointers.

Comment: Interesting, I'll have a look. Thanks.

Comment: BTW: pygame has `pygame.time.get_ticks()` which you can use instead of `time.time()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it works exactly as you expect but it checks time reaction on red color in miliseconds, and it works without `time.sleep()`

```
import pygame
import random

# --- constants ---

FPS = 30

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED   = (255,   0,   0)

# --- main ---

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
pygame.display.set_caption('Test')

repeats = 5

testing = False
color = WHITE

current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

# random time to start test 
start_test = current_time + random.randint(1, 3)*1000 # 1000ms = 1s

# - mainloop -

fps_clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:

    # - events -

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if testing:
                end = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                print(end - start, 'ms')
                repeats -= 1

    # - other

    if repeats == 0:
        pygame.quit()
        exit()

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    # is it time to start displaying red color
    if not testing and current_time >= start_test:
        testing = True
        color = RED
        start = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        # display white color
        stop_test = current_time + 2*1000 # 1000ms = 1s

    # is it time to stop displaying red color
    if testing and current_time >= stop_test:
        testing = False
        color = WHITE
        # random time to start next test 
        start_test = current_time + random.randint(1, 3)*1000 # 1000ms = 1s

    # - draws -

    screen.fill(color)
    pygame.display.flip()

    fps_clock.tick(FPS)
```